# Inconsistent cursor theme Kubuntu 19.10

Tags: kubuntu, cursor, plasma-5

I have had inconsistent cursor themes in Kubuntu. This is the cursor going between Discord and the desktop. The cursor theme is set to Breeze. How do I fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalled the Snap version and installed the one from Flathub. The issue is gone now.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to your problem! In the future, mentioning the source of an application would be helpful because snaps and flatpaks may behave differently than conventional .deb applications mostly installed via `sudo apt install`